# How change the screen saturation?

Tags: windows

Can I change the screen saturation in the registry? If not, where is the file/parameter with the screen saturation setting?

Comment: If you can't find a "grayscale" option in the registry then what exactly ***are*** you showing us? What does the option shown actually do? What are you expecting this "grayscale" option to do? What "grayscale" option are you talking about? Your question seems to assume we can see over your shoulder and see what you are seeing but is missing a lot of context.

Comment: I probably should have asked a slightly simpler question. Can I change the screen saturation in the registry?

Comment: If not, where is the file/parameter with the screen saturation setting?

Comment: Through the registry, at maximum you can turn grayscale on/off. If you want a gradual response, you'll have to somehow modify the display driver. Programs which change the screen color such as bluelight filters, do this. I'd start [from a list of these](https://alternativeto.net/software/f-lux/), individuate an open source, and look at their code.

Comment: If instead it's enough for you to change the saturation of your MONITOR programmatically (not all monitors allow this), you might look at something as [ClickMonitorDDC](https://github.com/chrismah/ClickMonitorDDC7.2)

Comment: (IF your CPU is Intel)  For a start you might also want to look at the [Intel Graphics Control Center](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/graphics/graphics-command-center.html), which lets you [change the saturation](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Saturation-on-Windows-10)

Comment: AMD, NVIDIA and other GPU manufacturers also have their own display control panel. You could make a change, and use an app such as Nirsoft's Registry Changes View, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html , to find what value has changed.

Comment: Indeed. In the video card settings there is a parameter responsible for the Intensity. I will look in this direction. Thank you all!

Comment: @drmoishe-pippik Very useful program!